# How to make ansible cater for different types of apache virtualhosts

Tags: ansible

I started studying ansible as a viable configuration management tool for office, setting up test environment etc. I have managed to cover most basic usage scenarios usage of playbooks for outlining tasks and orchestrating with roles.

I have created a very simple apache2 roles for specific scenario like document vhost and mod_proxy vhost. I got stuck,I can't figure out how to write playbook to execute those differents vhosts configuration on the same hosts ie domain `node1.localhost` pointing to `/var/www/vhosts/node1.localhost` and `node2.localhost` doing a reverse proxy for another box on `tomcat ajp port`.

Below is my role:

```
#roles/apache/tasks/main.yaml
---
- name: Update apt cache
  apt: update_cache=yes

- name: Install Apache2
  apt: 
    name=apache2
    state=present

- name: Creating a Document virtualhost file
  template:
    src=http_vhost.conf.j2
    dest=/etc/apache2/site-available/{{ apache_domain_name }}.conf
    mode=0644
    when: document_vhost == True

- name: Creating a Reverse Proxy virtualhost file
  template:
    src=http_vhost_reverse_proxy.conf.j2
    dest=/etc/apache2/site-available/{{ apache_domain_name }}.conf
    mode=0644
    when: proxy_vhost == True

- name: Activate Vhosts
  command: a2ensite {{ apache_domain_name }}.conf
  when: activate_vhost|bool
  notify: Reload Apache

- name: Deactivate Vhosts
  command: a2dissite {{ apache_domain_name }}.conf
  when: deactivate_vhost|bool
  notify: Reload-Apache
```

Document vhost template file

```
#roles/templates/http_vhost.conf.j2
<VirtualHost *:{{ apache_port }}>
    ServerAdmin {{ apache_admin_email_address }}
    ServerName {{ apache_domain_name }}
    {% if apache_domain_aliases is defined %}
        {% for serveralias in apache_domain_aliases %}
            ServerAlias {{ serveralias }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts{{ apache_domain_name}}/htdocs
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts{{ apache_domain_name}}/htdocs>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/{{ apache_domain_name }}_error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel {{ apache_log_level|default('warn') }}

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/{{ apache_domain_name }}_access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

Reverse Proxy vhost template file

```
#roles/apache/templates/http_vhost_reverse_proxy.conf.j2
<VirtualHost *:{{ apache_port }}>

    ProxyRequests off    
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ServerAdmin {{ apache_admin_email_address }}
    ServerName {{ apache_domain_name }}
    {% if apache_domain_aliases if defined %}
        {% for serveralias in apache_domain_aliases %}
            ServerAlias {{ serveralias }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if apache_vhosts if defined %}

        {% for vhost in apache_vhosts %}

           ProxyPass {{ vhost.apache_proxy_context }} {{ vhost.reversed_server_mod }}://{{ vhost.reversed_server_ip }}:{{ vhost.reversed_server_port }}{{ vhost.reversed_server_context }}
           ProxyPassReverse {{ vhost.apache_proxy_context }} {{ vhost.reversed_server_mod }}://{{ vhost.reversed_server_ip }}:{{ vhost.reversed_server_port }}{{ vhost.reversed_server_context }}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/{{ apache_domain_name }}_error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel {{ apache_log_level|default('warn') }}

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/{{ apache_domain_name }}_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Let's say I have the node IP 192.168.56.106 and should handle both `node1.localhost` regular vhost and `node2.localhost` proxy vhost.

Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1):

The way you set up your variables (using the same variable names for both the regular and proxy vhost) won't work. It's not an ansible problem (ansible doesn't care), Apache won't be happy with the resulting files. You can't have 2 different configs configured for the same FQDN. Also you use the same filename for both confis, so the proxy config will clobber any existing vhost config with the same name.

The name schema looks like it would work fine with only vhost or proxy config active, but if you want both active on one host you are going to have to rethink your variable names or how you want to use them. Maybe something like the following so you only have to define exceptions?

```
{{ proxy_apache_domain_name | default(apache_domain_name) }}
```

As far as controlling which config should be active on which host, I'd set the default value for document_vhost and proxy_vhost to false in the defaults/main.yml of the role, and then turn them selectively on per host in the host_vars of the hosts.

This should allow you to turn specific configurations on/off on a host basis.

roles/apache/defaults/main.yaml

```
document_vhost: False
proxy_vhost: False
```

host_vars/192.168.56.106

```
document_vhost: True
proxy_vhost: True
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was actually thinking of a way to loop inside the `roles/apache/tasks/main.yml` by changing the way tasks are called in order to pick a list or so from the playbook. That way a section of the tasks like creating and/or enabling of vhosts would be iterated over. Probably I that's because I come from a programming mind. Your inputs made me think about differents scenarios. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late and might not answer your direct question but there are roles that does most of these tasks https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-apache